# Error while cleaning up onAuthStateChanged inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

i return the onAuthStateChanged unsubscribe() function to cleanup the useEffect but it doesnt unsubcribe. what may be causing this bug?

```
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if(user){
                setInterval(()=>{
                    setUser(user)
                    history.push('/home')

                }, 1500)
            }
            else if(!user){
                setInterval(()=>{
                    history.push('/login')
                    
                }, 1500)
            }
        })
        return ()=> unsubscribe()
    }, [])
```

Comment: why is there a `setInterval`?  using setInterval in state changes isn't the best approach. My guess would be that is what is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problems with the code above, first `setInterval` is necessary I believe, second, you are returning a closure instead of the function itself, onAuthStateChange returns a function when the state changes so can you try this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if(user){
               setUser(user)
               history.push('/home')
            }
            else {
                history.push('/login')
            }
        });

        return unsubscribe();
    }, [])
```